# Moving SQLite .db file from server to client over http to a client location without download prompt

Tags: file, sqlite, http

I have a scenario where I need to move a SQLite .db file generated on the server to the client when the client requests.This has to happen over HTTP. Also the file has to be copied to a directory on the client location without any download prompt

Please can you advice how I can go about doing this in java/Servlets?

Comment: So you want to trigger it in a Webbrowser?

Comment: Ops. Post is 4 years old.